# Swig - wrapping C struct

Tags: python, c, struct, swig

I am trying to write Python wrap for C code which uses struct.

**modules.c:**

```
struct foo
{
    int a;
};

struct foo bar;
```

modulues.i

```
%module nepal
%{
    struct foo
    {
        int a;
    }
%}

extern struct foo bar;
```

But during compiling I am given error:

In function ‘Swig_var_bar_set’:
error: ‘bar’ undeclared (first use in this function)

Could you be so kind to help me how to correctly define export struct variable ?

Comment: Have you considered using the `ctypes` module instead of SWIG?  It's a whole lot easier.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
%module nepal
%{
    struct foo
    {
        int a;
    };

    extern struct foo bar;
%}

struct foo
{
    int a;
};

extern struct foo bar;
```

The code in %{ %} is inserted in the wrapper, and the code below it is parsed to create the wrapper.  It's easier to put this all in a header file so it is not so repetitive:

**modules.h**

```
struct foo
{
    int a;
};

extern struct foo bar;
```

**modules.c**

```
#include "modules.h"
struct foo bar;
```

**modules.i**

```
%module nepal
%{
    #include "modules.h"
%}

%include "modules.h"
```